# Project Euler #1: Reason behind inconsistent results from different methods

Tags: javascript

I have coded two methods to solve the problem. One is using a for loop and the other is using AP series formula.

```
function usingAP (limit) {
    var sum3 = sumAP(3, 3, Math.floor((limit - 1) / 3)),
        sum5 = sumAP(5, 5, Math.floor((limit - 1) / 5)),
        sum15 = sumAP(15, 15, Math.floor((limit -1 ) / 15));
    return sum5 - sum15 + sum3;
}

//function usingFor (limit) {
//    var sum = 0;
//    for (; limit--; ) {
//        if (limit % 3 === 0 || limit % 5 === 0) {
//            sum += limit;
//        }
//    }
//    return sum;
//}

function usingFor (limit) {
    var sum = 0,
        sum1 = 0,
        conflictThreshold = 196474635,
        useComparisonSeriesToDebugGlitch = limit > conflictThreshold,
        isFirstTerm = true,
        diff = NaN;
    for (; limit--; ) {
        if (limit % 3 === 0 || limit % 5 === 0) {
            sum += limit;
        }
        if (useComparisonSeriesToDebugGlitch) {
            if (!isFirstTerm) {
                if (limit % 3 === 0 || limit % 5 === 0) {
                    sum1 += limit;
                }
            } else {
                isFirstTerm = false;
            }
            if (sum - sum1 - conflictThreshold !== diff) {
                diff = sum - sum1 - conflictThreshold;
                console.log(limit, '|', sum, '|', sum1, '|', diff);
            }
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Until certain limit (conflictThreshold), both the methods give same result for same arguments. For any limit larger than that, I get inconsistent results.

I have setup some logging to find the reason behind this glitch.

Below is how the output looks like for consistent results.

```
======196474635======
using AP: 9007199081385435
using for loop: 9007199081385435
```

And below is how it looks like for inconsistent results:

```
======limit: 196474636======
using AP: 9007199277860070
196474635 '|' 196474635 '|' 0 '|' 0
9951 '|' 9007199254757828 '|' 9007199058283192 '|' 1
9945 '|' 9007199254787672 '|' 9007199058313035 '|' 2
9939 '|' 9007199254817492 '|' 9007199058342856 '|' 1
9935 '|' 9007199254837364 '|' 9007199058362727 '|' 2
...
2545 '|' 9007199276348940 '|' 9007199079874552 '|' -247
2541 '|' 9007199276354024 '|' 9007199079879637 '|' -248
2535 '|' 9007199276361636 '|' 9007199079887250 '|' -249
2529 '|' 9007199276369228 '|' 9007199079894841 '|' -248
2525 '|' 9007199276374280 '|' 9007199079899892 '|' -247
...
9 '|' 9007199277859724 '|' 9007199081385421 '|' -332
5 '|' 9007199277859736 '|' 9007199081385432 '|' -331
3 '|' 9007199277859740 '|' 9007199081385435 '|' -330
using for loop: 9007199277859740
```

I am trying to get my head around it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Please review [ask] and update your question to be a specific answerable question, rather than a code dump and some commentary.

Comment: That problem can be done with a single simple formula, no loops necessary. Read up on Karl Friedrich Gauss :)

Comment: I have rephrased my question. I want to understand the reason why these methods are failing to provide correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers you're working with are larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. Double-precision floating point numbers cannot represent the continuous set of integers beyond `9007199254740991`; there are "holes" in the number line beyond that. Thus you'll wind up with inaccuracies.

Comment: Similar thing is mentioned in this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER):
"For example, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1 === Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 2 will evaluate to true, which is mathematically incorrect."

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you would be willing to use just Javascript, but here is the solution I came up with:

```
<html>
<body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script text="javascript">
        var x = 0
        var y = 0

        while (x<1000){
            if ((x%3==0)||(x%5==0)){
            y=y+x;
            }
            x+=1;
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = y;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I implemented this solution as well. Turns out it is slow with large limits, hence other solutions.